# In my vue project i have tried using simple bootstrap along with sass and pug unable to use bootstrap. It's giving me error

Tags: vue.js, sass

Can i use bootstrap in a vue project along side sass. Is there any way to use bootstrap classes with pug.

I have tried to install bootstrap using this tutorial:https://travishorn.com/adding-bootstrap-to-a-vue-cli-project-98c2a30e0ed0
when i add the following commands in main.js file.
import 'bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

It is giving me:
  No PostCSS Config found in: /home/sidra/gekko/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css
    at /home/sidra/gekko/web/vue/node_modules/postcss-load-config/index.js:51:26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might be late with my answer, but I will answer, anyway, because I had the same issue today.

The idea is that `package.json` is storing your PostCSS configuration. So, you need to at least add PostCSS `options` key if it wasn't set yet:

```
"postcss": {
    "options": {},
    "plugins": {
        "autoprefixer": {}
    }
}
```

**UPD**: by the way, I think this type of error appears with external CSS only and pug might not be related.